# JSON.NET Array conversion

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to convert a JSON array to a C# dictionary.
My Box class has "id" and "color" properties.

```
{
   "boxes" [
       {"id":0, "color":"red"},
       {"id":1, "color":"green"},
       {"id":2, "color":"blue"}
   ]
}
```

I've tried a few things, but haven't had any luck getting this to work yet.

```
List<Box> jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Box>>(File.ReadAllText(filePath));
```

Comment: Does it work for you if you simply do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<int, string>>(boxes)` ?

Comment: This is syntactically invalid. `{ "boxes": [ .. ] }` would be correct.

Comment: Good point @JeroenMostert, edited. 
This is a trimmed down version of what I'm using, and I missed that part.

Comment: @Fabjan "To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. "
I've decided to add a function for list -> dictionary.

Comment: @Idios I've updated my answer according to scenario that you work with

Answer (score 1):

Well the thing is that your Dictionary is in *nested* property. 
And even more - it's not really a *dictionary*. It is an array of objects where each object consists of two fields - `id` and `color` (whereas in dictionary we have key-value pairs).

You could deserialize your json into anonymous object with correct structure and then get the array of boxes out of it and convert it to dictionary:

```
var box = new { id = 0, name = "" };
var jsonObj = new { boxes = new[] { box } };

var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(myJson, jsonObj).boxes
                                 .ToDictionary(b => b.id, b => b.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesn't need {} at the top level - so you can just have your list of items in {}'s surrounded by [].

```
[
    {"id":0, "color":"red"},
    {"id":1, "color":"green"},
    {"id":2, "color":"blue"}
]
```